# Shift+CapsLock to toggle caps lock functionality

Tags: macos, keyboard

I used [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) to change my caps lock button to forward delete. This disables any kind of capslock functionality. I am looking to have shift + Caps lock toggle the original caps lock functionality.

I cannot figure out how to add a new change key with the shift modifier.

Comment: Sort of a solution would be using Popclip extension "UpperCase" at https://pilotmoon.com/popclip/extensions/page/Uppercase

Answer (score 2):

As Seil only affects the CapS Lock key itself, it's not going to be listening for anything other than that.

I'm sure it would be easier overall to restore the Caps Lock key & just use Fn-Delete for forwards delete.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US for the full set of key commands.

Answer (score 1):

Karabiner offers a way:

```
Shift_R+Shift_L to CapsLock (+ Shift_L to turn CapsLock off)
```